# Dashboard table selection versus filter

Tags: dashboard

I am working on a dashboard for applications. I have one widget App List where all applications are listed and once I select an application it gets added on top with filter icon and other widgets react to it. In the image below I have selected App1 and see details for that application in other widgets. Now I see App2 and App3 are not critical and I want to delete those. I do not want to remove App1 from page level filter and yet somehow select App2 and App3 and delete it from App List. Can someone please suggest where they have tried to solve the case where filter and bulk action is done in same table or any web applications\products doing something similar?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface solution is quite simple.
Depending on how advanced the code is, it can be simple or difficult to implement

Also. if you don't wan't to see every "App Name" with High Status,
at the top of the page, you can add labels with filters to delete.

[image: enter preformatted text here]

---

edit:

Changing mode from normal to delete mode.
(In delete mode it's possible to select all without changing anything.

[image]

Comment: the question was about bulk action. I want to select delete App2, App3....and so on and delete at one go and not one by one

Comment: Ok, so App1 is selected, just implement multi select, (select App1, App2 - sygnalised by blue color) and click bulk action upper.

Comment: The moment I select App2 and App3 in similar fashion as App1 then other widgets also start changing to react to all three apps as that kind of selection is reserved for dashboard update. But here I don't need the dashboard to update for App2 and App3 just simply perform bulk action on that particular widget

Comment: ok i understand - tomorrow i think about it and try help You

Comment: @user1796650 ok i have proposition in edit

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for.